# Le français de la période de Voltaire

Tags: grammaire, usage, syntaxe

**EDIT**

Actuellement je lis le livre [Candide ou l'Optimisme](https://www.ebooksgratuits.com/blackmask/voltaire_candide.pdf) de Voltaire.

Voyant des mots désuets comme *icelui* je me demande quels éléments de la langue française de cette période-là sont considérés aujourd'hui comme archaïques quant à la **syntaxe** et à la **grammaire**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il y a plusieurs listes. C'est difficile de trouver quelque chose de précis.

Orthographes qui étaient utilisées avant la réforme orthographique française de 1835. Ces orthographes ne sont plus en usage actuellement, et considérées comme archaïques :
[https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Catégorie:français_moderne_d’avant_1835](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:fran%C3%A7ais_moderne_d%E2%80%99avant_1835)

Désuet et/ou archaïque : 
[https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Catégorie:Termes_désuets_en_français](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Termes_d%C3%A9suets_en_fran%C3%A7ais)
[https://fr.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Catégorie:Termes_archaïques_en_français](https://fr.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Cat%C3%A9gorie:Termes_archa%C3%AFques_en_fran%C3%A7ais)

Comment trouver ces informations par soi-même :

1. Moteur de recherche google en français
2. Chercher : "français désuet liste"
3. wiktionary et les catégories sont de très bon moyen d'agrégation de l'information.

Comment: C'est super ! Je vous remercie vivement.